# React Navigation Typescript Error On Stack Navigator

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm having a typescript issue with creating a stack navigator using React Navigation in combination with a component wrapped with a couple Higher Order Components (HOCs). I'm using `compose` to string my HOCs together but typescript is saying the returned component is not compatible with stack nagivator screen prop. Here is my code:

```
import { createStackNavigator, StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { RouteProp } from '@react-navigation/native';

type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: IProps
};

type IProps = {
  message: string;
  user: string;
  navigation: StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, 'Home'>;
  route: RouteProp<RootStackParamList, 'Home'>
}

const Home = (props: IProps) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => alert(props.message)} title='Message' />
    </View>
  );
}
const withMessage = (Component: React.ComponentType<{ message: string }>) => <Component message='hello' />
const withUser = (Component: React.ComponentType<{ user: string }>) => <Component user='Joe' />

const homeWithMoreProps = compose<IProps, {}>(
  withMessage,
  withUser
)(Home);

const RootStack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

<RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'>
  <RootStack.Screen name='Home' component={homeWithMoreProps} /> // <-- Error is here
</RootStack.Navigator>
```

Using "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.0-alpha.58"

The error is:

```
Type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<{ route: RouteProp<RootStackParamList, "Home">; navigation: any; }>': route, navigation
```

Basically telling me the `homeWithMoreProps` component is missing the navigation and route props, but based on my IProps typing it shouldn't be. I'm trying to follow these instructions but to no avail: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/typescript.html.

Comment: But from the error message it seems like the type of the component has only `{ children?: ReactNode; }`

Comment: Well there it is. Seems like compose is not returning the type I'm expecting. I don't know why it thinks there are no props in the returned element when I'm explicitly passing `IProps` into the compose types. In any case I was able to get around this error by making a type assertion on the element returned by the `compose` function like so `compose(...)(Home) as React.ComponentType<IProps>` which has fixed the problem.